# It was the best school for me to go to

Tags: to-infinitive

1. It *was* the best school *for me to have gone to*.
2. It *was* the best school *for me to go to*.

What is the difference between (1) and (2)? Can I replace the "was" in them with "is" without changing their meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of explanation, suppose the school in question was named “Question School.”

What to say depends on whether you already went (or not) to Question School and if so, whether or not you are still there.

1. Question School was the best school for me to have gone to.

This strongly suggests that you did in fact go to Question School. Changing “was” to “is” doesn't make a big difference, but it is a little more suggestive that you are still there. It’s not terrible to say 1. (but not with “is” instead) if you went elsewhere, but in that case, it might be better to say “Question school would have been the best school for me to have gone to.”

2. Question School was the best school for me to go to.

This is less indicative of your having actually gone to Question School, but might be a little better than 1. if you went to Question School and are still there. If you change “was” to “is” in this sentence, it makes a difference. You would only say “Question School is the best school for me to go to.” if you have some future choice — that going to Question School (or not) is something that will occur in the future.